# Adding to an already set/filled array

Tags: java, arrays

Is it possible to do this? I want to be able to give the user the option to add another element to the array which is set to the length 5 and has already been filled. I believe this will increase the array length by 1? Also, please know that I know how to do this in ArrayList. I want to be able to do this in a normal array.

I heard that `Arrays.copyof()` can help do this but I don't understand how?

Comment: Did you look at the source code of the `add` method of the `ArrayList`? That should give you an idea. Also did you look at the documentation of `Arrays.copyOf()`?

Comment: use ArrayList instead of Arrays.this way you can add elements at runtime.

Comment: `Arrays.copyOf(original, newLength)` is already the solution. It returns a new array with a length of `newLength` that contains the same elements in the same order as the original array. If `newLength` is greater than the original length that the new array has padding elements. If the opposite is the case, the array is cropped.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add one more element if your array is filled.

You need to build a bigger array and copy the values from the old array to the new one. That's where `Arrays.copyOf` comes in handy.

For performance reason, it would be better to add more than 1 empty cell each time you rebuild a new array. But basically, you will build your own implementation of `ArrayList`.

Comment: Yes, my question is how do I use Arrays.copyOf. I don't really understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

int[] myArray = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5}; //The array of five

int[] myLongerArray = Arrays.copyOf(myArray, myArray.length + 1); //copy the original array into a larger one

myLongerArray[myLongerArray.length-1] = userInput;  //Add the user input into the end of the new array
```

---

If you're going to be adding a lot of elements, instead of making the array one element larger each time, you should consider doubling the size of the array whenever it gets full.  This will save you copying all of the values over each time.

[Here is another example of using copyOf()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arrays_copyof_int.htm)

Answer (score 0):

In an ArrayList you can just add another value without having to do anything.  Internally, the ArrayList will create a new, larger array, copy the old one into it, and add the value to it.

If you want to do this with an array, you will need to do this work yourself.  As you are thinking, Arrays.copyOf() is a simple way to do that.  For instance:

```
    int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5};
    System.out.println(a.length); // this will be 5
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a)); // this will be [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    int[] b = Arrays.copyOf(a, 10);
    System.out.println(b.length); // this will be 10, half empty
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b)); // this will be [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Object> name = ArrayList<Object>();
name.add(userInput);
```

It's much better, more efficient. Also has convenient methods for use (especially add(Object), indexOf(Object), get(Object), remove(Object)).